# Set proxypass domain from header

Tags: apache, nginx, mod-proxy, proxypass, hostheaders

Trying to find a way to implement a proxypass based on the incoming header.

For instance:

```
proxyPass / https://%{{x-backend-host}}/
```

Where X-backend-host will be in the request headers.

The idea behind this is to have multiple incoming domains, i.e one.example.com, two.example.com, three.example.com and have them point at there own unique backends.

Does anyone have any ideas or references I can look at to implement a scenario like this.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this via a rewrite rule of mod_rewrite. From the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) of ProxyPass:

```
 If you require a more flexible reverse-proxy configuration, see the RewriteRule directive with the [P] flag.
```

Read hear about RewriteRule:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule
(scroll down where the differen flags are described and look for the [P] flag)